# Call async method during automapper mapping

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to learn automapper (version 10.0.0) and I'm setting up my DTO input object to become my Entity Framework model object, so I did this:

```cs
CreateMap<RequestInputDTO, Request>()
    .ForMember(x => x.RequestedById, x => x.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.RequestedForId, x => x.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.OrgHierarchyId, x => x.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dst) => {
        dst.Uuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        dst.RequestedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    });
```

And so far that part is working fine.  However, for those three properties I told it to ignore, I have to do database lookups.  They send me a name for example, I grab the ID of the corresponding record and then use that for the ID.  So when I receive the request I'm doing this:

```cs
var request = _mapper.Map<Request>(dto);
request.RequestedById = await WwidToIdAsync(dto.RequestedByWwid);
request.OrgHierarchyId = await OrgHierarchyNumberToIdAsync(dto.RequestedForOrgHierarchyCode);
request.RequestedForId = await WwidToIdAsync(dto.RequestedForWwid);
```

While that seems to be doing the right thing, I don't like that I've now disconnected those three items from the automapping.  It'd be too easy for someone to forget to do it.  I can't figure out how to get the three lines handled automatically during the mapping since `AfterMap` isn't async.

Comment: You cannot. Write a function that calls `Map` and the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with .NET 6.0. I don't know if you had the issue on Core or prior versions, but here's a solution (or maybe workaround) for AutoMapper 11 and .NET 6.0 (can be applied to any Core version, because it is using dependency injection).

1. I've added a new service where mentioned async methods are located:

```
    // Input and output parameter types were defined based on guessing from names :)
    public interface IMyService
    {
        Task<bool> WwidToIdAsync(bool requestedByWwid);
        Task<int> OrgHierarchyNumberToIdAsync(bool requestedForOrgHierarchyCode);
    }    

    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public async Task<bool> WwidToIdAsync(bool requestedByWwid)
        {
            // Your db lookup here
        }
    
        public async Task<int> OrgHierarchyNumberToIdAsync(bool 
                     requestedForOrgHierarchyCode)
        {
            // Another db lookup here
        }
    }
```

2. Register the service above in dependency container:

```
    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
```

3. Here's where all the magic happens: creating new MappingAction and injecting IMyService to it.

```
public class RequestInputMappingAction : IMappingAction<RequestInputDTO, Request>
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public RequestInputMappingAction(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public void Process(RequestInputDTO source, Request destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.Uuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        destination.RequestedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        destination.RequestedById = _myService.WwidToIdAsync(source.RequestedByWwid).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        destination.OrgHierarchyId = _myService.OrgHierarchyNumberToIdAsync(source.RequestedForOrgHierarchyCode).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        destination.RequestedForId = _myService.WwidToIdAsync(source.RequestedForWwid).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

4. And the final step - `CreateMap`

```
CreateMap<RequestInputDTO, Request>()
            .AfterMap<RequestInputMappingAction>();
```

Comment: so you don't await the async methods (WwidToIdAsync, for example) ? The method `public void Process` needs to return a task and we cannot call async methods there until then. But then we aren't implementing the interface `IMappingAction<RequestInputDTO, Request>`

Comment: This isn't async (as it's doing blocking wait for the result) but it's also a good way to get deadlocks in your code
See [link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to make an object over the source model, which contains fields for the async results. I then calculate the async results before using AutoMapper.

```cs
public class GetBytesObjectResponse // the wrapped source model.
{
    public GetObjectResponse Response { get; } // the original source model.
    public byte[]? Contents { get; private set; }

    private GetBytesObjectResponse(GetObjectResponse response)
    {
        Response = response;
    }

    public static async Task<GetBytesObjectResponse> From(GetObjectResponse response)
    {
        // Aurora uses AutoMapper to convert between Models. AutoMapper does not support async mappings.
        // so must do it separately.
        var a = new GetBytesObjectResponse(response);
        
        await Task.Run(async () => await a.ApplyStreamContents(response.ResponseStream).ConfigureAwait(false))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return a;
    }

    private async Task ApplyStreamContents(Stream stream)
    {
        Contents = await stream.ReadAllBytesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

```cs
CreateMap<GetBytesObjectResponse, GameCloudFile>()
    .ForMember(t => t.Path, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.Key))
    .ForMember(t => t.Size, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.ContentLength))
    .ForMember(t => t.Hash, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.Headers.ContentMD5))
    .ForMember(t => t.ModifiedTime, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.LastModified))
    .ForMember(t => t.ReadPermission, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-read-permission"]))
    .ForMember(t => t.OriginalAuthor, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-original-author"]))
    .ForMember(t => t.Version, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Response.VersionId))
    .ForMember(t => t.Contents, o => o.MapFrom((s) => s.Contents))
    .ForMember(t => t.ContentType, o => o.MapFrom((s) => s.Response.Headers.ContentType ?? "text/plain"));
```

It may not be the best but it was the best I could think of.